# Want to make work more efficient by using "hotstrings" for files and websites. Have tried AHK but would like a "terminal"

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, workflow, powershell

I use Windows 10 and I need to access a lot of local files, websites etc and need easy shortcuts for increased efficiency. I have tried Autohotkey but the amount of files i want to access makes it problematic. I tend to forget the commands etc.

Instead I would like to use some kind of "terminal window" on my desktop, and be able to program it with tons of easy-to-remember-"hotstrings". And also the ability to print all commands if necessary. For an example: if I Want to see the july 2019 GDP prognosis. Then just type "GDP July 2019" in the terminal and the correct file opens.

Can this be done in Powershell or what's the best way (software) to do this? It seems like it would be a somewhat common issue and that one could really speed things up using shortcuts like this.

Comment: Looks like you need some file indexing/searching software that has very flexible search input. Not necessarily a command line program IMO. Try to search the site with terms like [search+index+files](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+search+index+files) or [find+files](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+find+files)